# multiple Database mirroring in 1 server instance

Tags: sql-server, database, mirroring

Is it possible to mirror 3 databases on 2 servers,

ie.
On server 1 
database1, database2, database3

On server 2
mirrored database1, database2, database3

My admin claims due to endpoints its not possible to mirror 3 dbs from 1 server to another and one must use 3 servers each with 1 db...

Any help appreciated, also links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mirroring set up with 3 databases per server on MS SQL 2008. They're all using common endpoints, so I just have one endpoint on each server.

I'm also using a 3rd server as witness here, but that isn't very relevant, just to let you know that that  too does work.

Comment: Many thanks, as to dani comment, was directed at ms sql...wasn't even aware there was mirroring on mysql :-(

Comment: I expected that, tagged sql-server now that I'm sure :-)